# Upload temporary file in django rest framework

Tags: django, file-upload, django-rest-framework, temporary-files

I'm trying to create a way to upload xlsx files and then use celery to perform some actions.

I'm thinking this:

- A view to upload the file and save it temporarily
- Use celery to execute what I want in the file and then delete it.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```py
class ImportMyFileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )

    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
        my_file = request.data["file"]
        with open(f"/tmp/{my_file.name}", "wb+") as destination:
            for chunk in my_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
        # call_celery_here()
        ...
        Return something
```

I can generate the file where I want, but the problem is that when I open xlsx. I get this here:

```sh
--X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

PK<q^Q_rels/.rels���J1��}��{w�Dd���ЛH}���a7�0u}{�Z���I~��7C��f�G�Fo�Z+���{�����kW�#�VJ$cʪ��l� �n�0�\Q�X^:�`���d�d{�m]_�d����h��V����F�w�^F9��W��-�(F/3�O�DSU�N�l/w�{N(�[��q��T����u<��r�?焮�s9�F����M��h���'h?PKf����
```

Is there any detail missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, relying on DRF's built in functionality:

```
import os

from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class UploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()

class UploadView(APIView):
    ...
    def post(self, request):
        ser = UploadSerializer(request.data)
        ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        fs = FileSystemStorage(tempfile.gettempdir())
        file_name = fs.save(content=ser.validated_data['file'])
        full_path = os.path.join(fs.location, file_name)

        celery_func.delay(file_name=full_path)
        return Response("Upload OK")
```

A more robust way to do this would be to create a model representing your uploads to be processed, and use [the django model's FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield).

```
class Todo(models.Model):
   xlsx_file = models.FileField(...) # read the docs on this
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class UploadView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
       ...
       todo = Todo.objects.create(
           xslx_file = ser.validated_data['file']
       )
       celery_func.delay(todo_id=todo.pk)
       return Response("Upload OK")
```

Once this works you can look into using a [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) either alone, or paired with a [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).  Thats a bigger learning curve though.